# Failed to install spring-dm 1.2.1 in Karaf 2.2.5

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I am a newbie to karaf. I tried to install spring-dm 1.2.1 in karaf 2.2.5.
It failed with following error message:

Error executing command: Manifest not present in the first entry of the zip mvn:org.springframework.osgi/spring-osgi-annotation/1.2.1

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.  I suspect you've picked up a corrupt artifact, have a look in your local repo, try opening it with a zip application.

Are you installing it directly in the Karaf shell or via a feature?  If it's via a feature and the artifact isn't corrupt try installing it from the Karaf shell - if that works it may be a bug in Karaf features or an error in your features file